# Prevent Publishing Node Application

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have a nodeJS application that I am working on, which has a package.json file and some node-module dependencies. I do **NOT** want the application to ever be published on node. Only eventually will I host my application with something like Heroku. I am really concerned about it being published somehow. How do I have control and know that my application is not currently published.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your package.json file, just set:

```
"private": true
```

Then, NPM won't publish it, even by accident.  I also recommend setting `"license": "UNLICENSED"`.

See also:  https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Comment: What does the license part do?

Comment: @CodeRocks You should read the documentation I linked to.  It doesn't *do* anything on its own, but has a legal ramification if you were to accidentally open access to your GitHub repo or something similar.  The `UNLICENSED` value implies that no license is given to anyone for using your software.